# Trying to create a piece of code that acts like a switch being toggle on or off

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Switch(toggle = 0):
    if toggle == 0:
        toggle = 1
        while toggle == 1:
            print('hello world')

    else:
        toggle = 0
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

This is the code that I have but my problem is when I press my designated hotkey it never stops printing even when I press it again

Comment: if you reached this `while toggle == 1:` and the result was true, then of course it'll begin with an infinite loop since toggle will be always 1 and no changes on it happens

Comment: do you only want to print `hello world` with `0.3` time sleep. Also, your else will not work because of default toggle value your if condition will always be `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you never set `toggle = 0` when you enter

```
while toggle == 1:
            print('hello world')
```

Probably you need

```
while toggle == 1:
            toggle = 0
            print('hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

you set toggle =1 after if and used while loop on it. obviously it will be printing infinite times. you must define how many times you want to toggle the switch. here is the code:-

```
import time
def Switch(a):
    toggle=0
    for i in range(0,a):
        if toggle == 0:
            toggle = 1
            while toggle == 1:
                toggle=0
                print('hello world')

        if toggle == 0:
            print("off")
            time.sleep(1)
Switch(5)
```

here i toggled it 5 times with 1 sec delay. i just edited your code. hope this will be helpful for u.